# VueJS not rendering in IE11

Tags: vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

I have a really large portion of our site written in VueJS. It was brought to my attention that it does not load in IE 11 (or Safari 9 and below). Unfortunately, IE 11, still accounts for 10% of traffic to the site.

After adding in polyfill and fixing some other errors in the developer console for IE11 the site still doesn't load. I see only a blank page. I set the compatibility mode to edge, nothing still. The console is clear of errors, only a few warnings. I am indeed running this through es2015 + babel-polyfill using gulp.

Has anyone dealt with this before? I am afraid I will have to start stripping down the application piece by piece until I isolate the code or element causing the problem. That could take days seeing as IE 11 gives me no debugging information.

Comment: I would suggest having a more static site for IE11 and below (the mobile static site fallback approach).

Comment: I'm open to the suggestion, if I can't get this working. How would one instruct IE11 to use the static version instead?

Comment: You don't, you set it up so that the failure of your prior code doesn't affect the static operation of the site. The idea being that any individual script or CSS failure shouldn't block users.

Comment: So render the static version by default and then let vuejs essentially overwrite what's there? Or add a hidden class to the parent "static site" element in VueJs.create()? That's a lot of additional data to pull down the pipe.

Comment: The former is what google recommends, it has the added benefit of letting users interact with the site before it's fully loaded. Basically phase in your enhancements. If you do it right you shouldn't be pulling down one byte more than you would otherwise.

Comment: It's an idea at least.

Comment: Failing that you should consider the 80/20 rule, if those 10% aren't driving enough business but are taking up 80% of your time, is it worth supporting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here was ES6 style JavaScript within the markup. Example:

```
<div class="tabs tab_select" data-group="tabs" data-ref="room" v-on:click="(event) => { toggleTab(event, property) }">
```

Needed to be:

```
<div class="tabs tab_select" data-group="tabs" data-ref="room" v-on:click="toggleTab(event, property)">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that my website was automatically running in compatibility mode as all sites on our intranet do.

What fixed the issue for me was using a meta tag setting the target to the version I needed (I needed to target a min of IE 10).

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Put that on your index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.5/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How will this help? Am I needing this for promises to work for IE 11?

Comment: This is exactly for the promises!

Comment: I added in a polyfill already for that, but I tried this anyways, of course it does not help because I already have a polyfill in.